# Sqlite C++ Image to Blob wont store nothing

Tags: c++, image, sqlite, blob, storage

I googled a lot and couldn't find any solution. I'm currently writing myself an 
app in Codegear 2007 C++. I'm writing this app for my little kittens, its kinda' a dairy 
but I call it KittyBook.

So i have two tables(sorry didn't understand how to CodeBlock) :

- Kitten Info
- Kitten Data.

KittenInfo Stores their names and their ID ( primary key ), their gender and their birth. This one works.

The other one should store a Blob. So after trying so many ways. It won't be stored in the table, not even the other data if I do the Query with normal insert but excluding the blob table.

So, I dunno what I'm doing wrong BUT I love SQLite so far. No turning back then eh?

The function is :

```
void CDatabase::InsertKittenData(int Kitten_ID, int kittenDay, bool DayOrWeek,
    char * kitten_weight, char * Kitten_Comment, string PhotoFile) {

    unsigned char * blob;

    ifstream::pos_type size;
    int size2 = 0;
    if (FileExists(PhotoFile.c_str())) {
        ifstream file(PhotoFile.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            size = file.tellg();
            blob = new char[size];
            file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
            file.read(blob, size);
            file.close();
        }

    }
    else {
        blob = NULL;
    }
    sqlite3 *dbp;
    sqlite3_stmt *ppStmt;
    // NULL = primary key autoinc.
    char * Sql = "INSERT INTO KittenData VALUES ( NULL, ? , ? ,? , ? , ? , ?);";


    int rc = sqlite3_open("KittyBook.db", &dbp);
    if (rc)
        return;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbp, Sql, -1, &ppStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        return;
    }

    if (ppStmt) {
        if (sqlite3_bind_int(ppStmt, 1, Kitten_ID) != SQLITE_OK)
            return;

        if (sqlite3_bind_int(ppStmt, 2, kittenDay) != SQLITE_OK)
            return;
        if (sqlite3_bind_int(ppStmt, 3, DayOrWeek) != SQLITE_OK)
            return;

        if (sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, 4, // Index of wildcard
            kitten_weight, strlen(kitten_weight), // length of text
            SQLITE_STATIC) != SQLITE_OK)
            return;
        if (sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, 5, // Index of wildcard
            Kitten_Comment, strlen(Kitten_Comment), // length of text
            SQLITE_STATIC) != SQLITE_OK)
            return;

        if (sqlite3_bind_blob(ppStmt, 6, blob, size2, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
            != SQLITE_OK)
            return;

        if (sqlite3_step(ppStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
            return;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(ppStmt);

    sqlite3_exec(dbp, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_close(dbp);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare and initialize `size2` as zero:

```
int size2 = 0;
```

then the next use of `size2` is when you bind the blob:

```
sqlite3_bind_blob(ppStmt, 6, blob, size2, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
```

From the [fine manual](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html):

> In those routines that have a fourth argument, its value is the number of bytes in the parameter. To be clear: the value is the number of bytes in the value, not the number of characters.

and the fourth argument in this case is `size2` and that's zero. The result is that you're telling SQLite to bind a zero-length blob and then you're wondering why nothing gets stored. Well, nothing gets stored because you're asking SQLite to store zero bytes and it is only doing what it is told.

Perhaps you want to use `size` instead of `size2`.

Comment: Ow thats my mistake, size2 i also removed. and used Size. 
all returns are passed by, so dunno where the problem should be.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the column names in your INSERT? Something like `insert into t (c1, c2, ...) values (...)`. You are reading something into `blob`, right?

Comment: in sqlite browser, if i use :

INSERT INTO KittenData(ID, Kitten_ID, Kitten_Date, Kitten_DayOrWeek, Kitten_Weight,Kitten_Comment) VALUES ( NULL, 1 ,2 ,1 ,"200" ,"volgende") ;

Comment: TY, after trying column by column in the Function, it finally works. cheers

Answer (score 0):

mu is too short, gave me the idea to do the Function step by step and increasing column 
by column. Dunno what i did wrong, but its working now.

Cheers  mu is too short :)